# How do I change a model's property from string to double?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Apologies, I am very new to the concept of MVC. I have the following code in my model:

```
public partial class Record
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Temperature { get; set; }
     public string Humidity { get; set; }
...
```

I want to my Temperature from a string to a double. How do I do this? Do I need to update my database?

Comment: Judging by the `partial` you're using something like Entity Framework or another ORM to create the mapping between your models and your database?

Comment: In short, you do need to update your database to match your model. However, the way in which you do that may depend on what you are using.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm using entity framework. How would I go about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parse function of double

For example: `double.Parse(Temperature, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

will return a double value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just change the data type? I basically need to change all the strings to doubles

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to change the database field from `string` to `double` in EF, use migrations:

1. Change your class field definition as needed (ie replace `string` with `double`)
2. Add a migration with `dotnet ef migrations add <name>`, and double check the migration file added to your project to ensure it's what you want.
3. Update the database with your latest migrations with `dotnet ef database update`.

Alternatively, and this is important to know in general, your model does not need to match your database. You can create a model separate from your EF context and use `AutoMapper` to copy the data from one to the other automatically. But yes, it makes no sense to store temperatures as strings.

Comment: Will definitely give this a try. By your second point where you added "<name>", is that the name of the database?

Comment: No, it's the name of the migration, ie a descriptive name of what you changed so you can keep track of the database changes across time (source control).